# Why does my bot just shut off on a reaction discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

so on all commands my bot just shuts off when you do an emoji.... why does this happen?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 443, in <module>
    bot.run("TOKEN")
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 598, in
 run
    return future.result()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 579, in
 runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 543, in
 start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 457, in
 connect
    await self._connect()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 421, in _connect
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 469, in poll_event
    await self.received_message(msg)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 423, in received_message
    func(data)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/state.py", line 409, in parse_message_reaction_add
    emoji = PartialEmoji.with_state(self, animated=emoji_data['animated'], id=emoji_id, name=emoji_data['name'])
KeyError: 'animated'
```

there is no animated nor emoji in the code...

help me

Comment: Which version of `discord.py` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're running your bot on an old version of `discord.py`.

Open your python env in your terminal and type the following :

```py
$ python3

import discord

discord.__version__
```

If you're running a version < 1.3 you should update your `discord` module using

```
$ pip3 install discord.py --upgrade
```